# unable to selet element which have been dynamically created using Ajax callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

In AJAX callback I am inserting a DIV with a peculiar ID into a given DIV A. Now after every call, if div with given id is not as a child element of DIV A, I am creating a new DIV and appending it. But everytime, $($id).length is returning 0, but div with $id is there. What can be possible issues here?

Something like this is happening:--

```
  $.post(,,function(){
    $id = "#123"//changes but can be same
          foo($id);
        });

        function foo(id) {
        if($(id).length == 0 ){
          $("#A").append("<div id='b'></div>");
        }
        }
```

Comment: '<div id="b"></div>'  Check double vs single quotes and let us know

Comment: Take a look at your browser's debugging console.  Your call to `.append()` has a syntax error which would be reported there.  *Always* check the debugging console.

Comment: You can debug jQuery issue from browser console @avinash

Comment: if that is your code you aren't creating an element with an id of your variable `id`. You are creating one as `b`. And if your actual code is using `id` then you are generating the code wrong as it would be using the selector as the value, eg end up with `<div id="#123"></div>` when it should be `id="123"`

Comment: If `$(id).length` is 0 then the count of elements found for that `id` selector is 0.  Perhaps you have a mistaken assumption somewhere?  You've changed the code to fix a syntax error since posting the question, are there any other differences between this and your actual code?  Do you have a complete (and minimal) example to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Thanks @PatrickEvans , what you have pointed, is exactly what I have missed.  I was creating the Id with #123 and searching with 123 thus missing every time.Now I am all good. Thanks everyone for reaching out .

Answer (score 0):

Where is your Array for storing your references?  $($id).length is a method to run on an Array.

To use .length, you would do something like this:

```
var divArray = [];
$.post(,,function(){
$id = "#123"//changes but can be same
      foo($id);
    });

    function foo(id) {
    divArray.push(id);
    if(divArray.length == 0 ){
      $("#A").append("<div id="b"></div>");
    }
}
```

Comment: [jQuery objects have a `length` property](https://api.jquery.com/length/) that represents the number of objects (actual js objects, html elements, etc) that it contains

Comment: It can also be used to find whether a div with given id is there or not.